# Rolling back a parent record does not remove child records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Rolling back a parent record does not seem to remove any new child records which might have been added to it. Not sure if this is a bug or feature.

```
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  employees: DS.hasMany('App.Employee')
});

App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.belongsTo('App.Company')
})

var company = App.Company.find(1);
//Initially: company.get('employees.length') => 0

var employee = company.get('employees').createRecord();
//Now: company.get('employees.length') => 1

employee.get('transaction').rollback();
//Still: company.get('employees.length') =>1
//Also: employee.get('isDeleted') => true

company.get('transaction').rollback();
//Even now: company.get('employees.length') =>1

//How do I rollback such that company.get('employees.length') == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a rollbackAll() method in my application that does depth-first traversal using get and promises, and then rolls them all back before rolling back the parent. It looks like this:

```
rollbackAll: function() {
  // recursively rollback on all children and self
  this.get('children').then(function (children) {
    children.forEach(function(child) {
      child.rollbackAll();
    });
  });
  this.rollback();
}
```

I should mention that that's because I happen to have recursive relationships in my application (ie a tree of objects, each of which can have its own parent).

The pattern here is that each model 'class' can get its own rollbackAll method where it knows how to roll back its own associations, and then it should just be a matter of calling rollbackAll() on each. (Deepest child first if you have multiple levels).